# Generated PDF file not opening automatically in Chrome

Tags: node.js, http, pdf, koa

I am currently implementing some functionaly in my Koa.js layer where when a method is called a PDF is generated and then returned to the user as a downloaded file. I currently cannot get this to work and cannot see why.

I can see in my Chrome network tab that the response headers are correct but it does not open so this leads me to suspect the body of the response is not correct but I can't see why.

Here is my code:

```
import Router from 'koa-router';
const PDFRouter = new Router();
import PDFDocument from 'pdfkit';

import PDFController from '../../../controllers/api/PDFController';
const PDFControllerInstance = new PDFController();

PDFRouter.post('/generate-pdf', async (ctx, next) => {
    let doc = new PDFDocument();
    const filename = 'claim';

    ctx.response.set('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"');
    ctx.response.set('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
    const PDFfile = ctx.res.pipe(doc);

    doc.end();
    ctx.body = PDFfile;
});

export default PDFRouter;
```

As you can see, I am using the PDFkit library to generate the PDF. The raw PDF code gets sent in the body in the response. Here are the request, response headers and body.

```
Request URL:http://degould-login.dev/api/generate-pdf
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://degould-login.dev
Connection:keep-alive
Content-disposition:attachment; filename="claim"
Content-Type:application/pdf
Date:Fri, 17 Nov 2017 15:22:56 GMT
Server:nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked

Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:11
content-type:text/plain
Cookie:XDEBUG_SESSION=XDEBUG_ECLIPSE
Host:degould-login.dev
Origin:http://degould-login.dev
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://degould-login.dev/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.89 Safari/537.36
```

And here is the response:

```
%PDF-1.3
%ÿÿÿÿ
5 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
/Contents 3 0 R
/Resources 4 0 R
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<<
/Producer (PDFKit)
/Creator (PDFKit)
/CreationDate (D:20171117152256Z)
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 1 0 R
>>
endobj
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Count 1
/Kids [5 0 R]
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Length 23
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
x3T0B]C ani¤ËI\
endstream
endobj
xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000327 00000 n 
0000000278 00000 n 
0000000384 00000 n 
0000000119 00000 n 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000186 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 7
/Root 2 0 R
/Info 6 0 R
>>
startxref
478
%%EOF
```

Here is my front-end service method that makes the request to the Node.JS (Koa) layer

```
generatePDF(PDFContent: string): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.post(this._config.API_URL + '/generate-pdf', PDFContent)
            .map((response) => response.json);
    }
```

Can anyone see what I have done wrong here or offer some advice? I want the PDF file to be downloaded automatically onto the client's computer.
Thanks

Comment: Is this in a specific version of Chrome?

Comment: No it's any browser.

Comment: How exactly are you making the request? Do you have some sort of form submission or are you manually making an AJAX request?

Comment: I will add the request details into my original question

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
ctx.response.set('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
```

with

```
ctx.response.set("Content-Type", "application/force-download")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This doesn't solve my issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I managed to get this fixed by doing the following. There was nothing wrong with my Node code, it was in my FE Angular4 code where the problem had arisen.

I amended my service function as follows:

```
generatePDF(PDFContent: string): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.post(this._config.API_URL + '/generate-pdf', PDFContent, { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob })
            .map((response) => {
                return response;
            });
    }
```

As the node layer was returning a blob to me I had incorrectly left response.json() in there. So this was removed.

Once I returned the blob back to my controller method from the service as shown above, I simply created a helper function to create a URL for the blob as follows and the PDF opened in a new window.

```
export const FileHelper = {
    downloadFile(data: Response): void {
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(data);
        window.open(fileURL);
    }
};
```

Hope this helps